# html5 website like benthebodyguard?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have no programming experience related to building websites. I want to build a simple website similar to http://benthebodyguard.com/index-b.php where people scroll downwards. And I would like to implement a good or bad voting functionality to 5-6 of the different images that are displayed on the website which the user interacts while scrolling down. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually uses the boilerplate template.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyM37XKkmKQ&feature=player_detailpage#t=323s

Answer (score 1):

You need to get some experience in web programming.

Find books about HTML, CSS, Javascript, and (my opinion) ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: ASP.Net MVC and index-b.php ??

Comment: @Falcon: He never said he wants to use PHP.  He just wants to copy a website which happens to be built in PHP.

Comment: sorr. my mistake. But all the way   ASP.Net MVC is too big for this.  He can use simple ruby framework like sinatra. or PHP

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I would agree with SLaks.  But you will have to start somewhere.  The best place I have found that helps you learn programming is [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com).  They have a lot of good tutorials.  So you can start learning how to put simple site together.

Comment: I'd like to learn by examples (preferably html5 similar to the website I have mentioned). I did some html,php,JS few years back. Do you know of any examples?

Comment: To be honest, you would need to get a good grounding in a programming language first.  Then you could look at the js quoted in one the other answers.  If you look at the examples it may not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need some web-dev experience.

How it works in benthebodyguard.com You can see here: http://benthebodyguard.com/js/speechBubbles.js?v=1.09